# how to restrict mongodb _id random value changes while we fetching from db and converting to entity

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb, spring-mongodb

```
public static synchronized Object convertToEntity(Class<?> entityClass, Map<String, Object> entityMap){
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        Object pojo = mapper.convertValue(entityMap, entityClass);
        return pojo;
}
```

here after converting value using mapper and pojo contains _id random value will be changed as compared
to which is stored in db like below

_id

6453a95 **ae82df6385d** 4e573e

6453a95 **a1800896d19** 4e573e

i tried many ways its getting change while fetching from db and when i tried to update its not updating since _id random value will be change and it wont find in db